# SwiftUI how to set the button style toggle taking the whole highlighted width

Tags: swiftui

I have 2 button styled toggles in a row like this:

[image]

I have set both widths to be infinite, so that they together take the whole space of the HStack.

However, when I turn on the toggle, the highlighted area is only the size of the toggle label. This looks bad because the 2 titles are different length.

Is it possible to expand the highlighted width so each of them takes half of the available screen width?

This is my code:

```
      
      HStack {
        SUITextToggle(label: loc(.roundUp), isOn: state.roundingType == .up) { _ in
          viewModel.toggleRoundingType(.up)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

        SUITextToggle(label: loc(.roundDown), isOn: state.roundingType == .down) { _ in
          viewModel.toggleRoundingType(.down)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
      }
```

And this is my toggle implementation:

```
public struct SUITextToggle: View {
  
  @State var isOn: Bool
  private var binding: Binding<Bool> {
    Binding<Bool> {
      return isOn
    } set: { newValue in
      isOn = newValue
      onChange(newValue)
    }
  }
  
  let label: String
  let onChange: (Bool) -> Void
  
  init(label: String, isOn: Bool, onChange: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    self.label = label
    self.isOn = isOn
    self.onChange = onChange
  }
  public var body: some View {
    Toggle(label, isOn: binding)
      .toggleStyle(.button)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code, to make the buttons expand the highlighted width so each of them takes half of the available screen width.

```
HStack {
    SUITextToggle(label: "roundUp", isOn: stateUp) { _ in
      viewModel.toggleRoundingType(.up)
    }
    SUITextToggle(label: "roundDown", isOn: stateDown) { _ in
      viewModel.toggleRoundingType(.down)
    }
}


public struct SUITextToggle: View {
  @State var isOn: Bool
    
  private var binding: Binding<Bool> {
    Binding<Bool> {
      return isOn
    } set: { newValue in
      isOn = newValue
      onChange(newValue)
    }
  }
  
  let label: String
  let onChange: (Bool) -> Void
  
  init(label: String, isOn: Bool, onChange: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    self.label = label
    self.isOn = isOn
    self.onChange = onChange
  }
  public var body: some View {
      Toggle(isOn: binding) {
          Text(label).frame(maxWidth: .infinity).contentShape(Rectangle()) // <-- here
      }
      .toggleStyle(.button)
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow it works. I am wondering why does setting the inner Text works but setting the outer Toggle doesn't work?